# facing Problem in finding id for name in Json value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5, angular6, angular-services

I am working on Angular project where I am facing problem in storing id of the name 
in a variable

exapmple :

```
[
{ttypeName: Cricket , ttypeUid: 1}
 {ttypeName: Hockey, ttypeUid: 2} , 
{ttypeName: nba, ttypeUid: 3}  , 
{ttypeName: football, ttypeUid:4}  , 
{ttypeName: kabadi, ttypeUid: 5}  ]
```

we have **name** , now we want to match the **MatchId** and store it in the variable and use it

**Note: JASON values are not static and length and order is not fixed ,values are coming from service**

I am posting my code below  ->

**explanation** I am passing **sportstype** in the function which contain **ttypeName**  I want to get it's **ttypeUid**

For that I write code :

```
this.responsesportstypedata.find(m => m.ttypeName == sportstype ).ttypeUid;
```

**Output: 
But this is returning wrong id , 
for eg it is returning ttypeUid : 3 for ttypeName: Cricket ;**

getmatchDetails(sportstype) {

```
           this.rest.getSportstype().then(
                 result => {
                  this.responsesportstypedata = result;


                  this.sportsUid =   this.responsesportstypedata.find(m => m.ttypeName == sportstype ).ttypeUid;


                },
                   err => {
                  this.router.navigate(['ErrorPage']);
                     }
                  );
```

Comment: please post some code of what have you tried so far, or what issue you are getting.

Comment: @SachinGupta

I have modified my code and posted my code also so kindly check

Answer (score 0):

what you need here is array.find()

```
let matchElement = results.find(t=>matchId == yourId);
```

Comment: I tried to work in the way which you suggested but it is not working , I have added more code and explained more  can you please check

Answer (score 0):

should be as I understood the problem

```
const nameToFindBy = '...';
const matchId = this.matches.find(m => m.name === nameToFindBy).MatchId;
```

Comment: I tried to work in the way which you suggested but it is not working , I have added more code and explained more  can you please check

Comment: @TestingAnurag are your sure that `this.responsesportstypedata` returns an array? any output to console? Can you debug line-by-line?

Comment: yes that is returning array (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: did you try to `console.log(this.sportsUid)` after assignment? Any console errors etc?